# File not copy to remote pc using ansible

Tags: file-copy, ansible

I am using `ansible-2.0` on linux machine and create the `ansible-galaxy`, on it created the `dns.yml` file which replace the `/etc/resolv.conf` on remote machine but it's not working. Ansible status showing `OK`.

dns.yml

```
---
- name: place dns configuration
  become: true
  template:
    src: resolv.conf.j1
    dest: /tmp/resolv.conf
```

Output :

```
....
TASK [lab : include ansible related tasks] *************************************
included: /home/adminto/ansible/lab/tasks/dns.yml for pc1

TASK [lab : place dns configuration] *******************************************
ok: [pc1]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
as                         : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

mypc# : ~/ansible$ ansible all -i 'pc1,' -c local -m ping
as | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
`enter code here`}
```

Error in Deep view :

```
admin:~/ansible$ sudo ansible-playbook -i "pc1," lab-data.yml -t dns.yml -vvvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0
1 plays in lab-push.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
<pc1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<pc1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/adminto/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt as '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487592713.4-221225682479967 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487592713.4-221225682479967 )" )'
<pc1> PUT /tmp/tmpPNuqMM TO /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487592713.4-221225682479967/setup
<pc1> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/adminto/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[as]'
<pc1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<pc1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/adminto/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt pc1 'LANG=en_IN LC_ALL=en_IN LC_MESSAGES=en_IN /usr/bin/python /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487592713.4-221225682479967/setup; rm -rf "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487592713.4-221225682479967/" > /dev/null 2>&1'
ok: [pc1]

TASK [lab : include ansible related tasks] *************************************
task path: /home/adminto/ansible/lab/tasks/main.yml:1
included: /home/adminto/ansible/lab/tasks/dns.yml for pc1

pc1                         : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Anyone have idea why this file is not copy even status showing `ok`.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. in your question you're mentioning `/etc/resolv.conf`, while the task you've created deploys the template in `/tmp/resolv.conf`. Change it like this:

```
---
- name: place dns configuration
  become: true
  template:
    src: resolv.conf.j1
    dest: /etc/resolv.conf
```

Check out your command: `sudo ansible-playbook -i "pc1," lab-data.yml -t dns.yml -vvvv`

- with `-t` you select a tag, are you sure that your tag is actually named `dns.yml`, as it sounds like a playbook name

Quite interesting inventory filename.

Comment: here temporary I've added `/tmp` because I was think, file is exist so that may not work. but here `resolve.conf` file is not copy to remote pc, Is there any way to troubleshooting same?

Comment: @Ravi In your test, was the file copied to /tmp?

Comment: Nop, even /tmp folder :(

Comment: What is your playbook structure? Is `resolv.conf.j1` located in the `templates` folder, or in `files` folder? And shouldn't `resolv.conf.j1` be actually named `resolv.conf.j2`, as the templates are Jinja2 ones?

Comment: `resolv.conf.j1` is in templates folder and change to ` resolv.conf.j2` but still not copy file; but in localhost, its working

Comment: Run the playbook again with `-vvvv` and copy the output to your question

Comment: I've added deep error view on my question, please check